# Vote count of 1000 and above is truncated with ellipsis (...)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, android-app

Vote count of 1000 and above is truncated with ellipsis (...).

I do not really have an issue with this one. If I see this, I'm going to assume that this is an interesting question / answer. However, stats geeks may disagree; and if this is the case, how can it be improved?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps if the vote count exceeds 1000, it becomes displayed in thousands? (3,422 -> 3.4k | 3,950 -> 3.9k | 1,000 -> 1k)

Comment: @ChrisForrence That's a good suggestion, although that would make it inconsistent with the Desktop mode view.

Comment: @geff_chang I'm fairly sure the desktop homepage already shows `kviews`.

Comment: Upvotes on questions could be limited to 999, or just wait, so highly upvoted questions are nowadays closed

Comment: @ŁukaszLech not if they're locked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of version 0.1.44 coming out later tonight the app will both truncate numbers to something like "1.2k" and dynamically resize the text to force it to fit, if needed:

[image]

Comment: Broken again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246243/unnecessary-ellipsis-in-mobile-app