# Unnecessary ellipsis in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

There is unnecessary ellipsis in some places where the actual text would fit just fine. The behavior appears to be inconsistent.

[image: Loading questio...]

Here, "*Loading question*" looks like it would fit, but "*Loading questio...*" is shown instead.

Nexus 5, Android 5.0.1 (Lollipop), Stack Exchange app 1.0.51.

Comment: Looks like [a previous bug fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198940/152859) is borked and "dynamically resize the text to force it to fit" is no longer happening.

Comment: It seems to be inconsistent. This should be the final edit for now, which clearly demonstrates it. (Yes, my battery is low, shut up! :P)

Comment: Weird. Let's hope the dev can also repro and fix it. :)

Comment: Huh, it seems the first image's resolution was truncated somehow, while the second image's was not, so it looks huge.

Comment: Looks like I just discovered a hidden feature of Imgur by accident? And I found the docs: https://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs

Comment: Hi, for easier bug management, we encourage to do 1 post/bug report, unless it's related. However, in this case, Exhibit A is not related to the Exhibit B at all (it's caused by different reason; in B, it has *108 answers*, not 10~19 answer). So, I'd suggest to remove the Exhibit B and post it as another question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The actual text is not 'Loading question' but 'Loading question...' (Note the extra dots)

Thus enough characters are removed to fit the ellipsis.

One change in the algorithm could be to allow dots to be removed without adding an ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, the text is replaced with 'Loading question' (without dots). The ellipsis will still be shown normally if the text really doesn't fit on smaller screen.

> [image: loading question]